# Tool to detect use/abuse of String.Concat (where StringBuilder should be used)

Tags: c#, .net, static-analysis, stringbuilder

It's common knowledge that you shouldn't use a StringBuilder in place of a small number of concatenations:

```
string s = "Hello";
if (greetingWorld)
{
    s += " World";
}

s += "!";
```

However, in loops of a significant size, StringBuilder is the obvious choice:

```
string s = "";
foreach (var i in Enumerable.Range(1,5000))
{
    s += i.ToString(); // <- bad idea!
}

Console.WriteLine(s);
```

Is there a tool that I can run on either raw C# source or a compiled assembly to identify **where** in the source code that `String.Concat` is being called?  (If you're not familiar, `s += "foo"` is mapped to `String.Concat` in the IL output.)  Obviously, I can't realistically search through an entire project and evaluate every `+=` to identify whether the lvalue is a string.

Ideally, it would only point out calls inside a for/foreach loop, but I would even put up with all the false positives of noting *every* `String.Concat`.  Also, I'm aware that there are some refactoring tools that will automatically refactor my code to use `StringBuilder`, but I am only interested in identifying the `Concat` usage at this point.

I routinely run Gendarme and FxCop on my code, and neither of those tools identify what I've described.  However, as [@Cristian pointed out](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2804554/tool-to-detect-use-abuse-of-string-concat-where-stringbuilder-should-be-used/2804849#2804849), older versions of FxCop used to check for this.  Maybe there's a way to extract just that rule from an old version of FxCop and tell the newer version (1.36) to use it?

Comment: Hmm, C# (or rather .NET) needs FindBugs.

Answer (score 3):

Perhaps NDepend [CQL](http://www.ndepend.com/CQL.htm) (Code Query Language) is expressive enough for this. Not sure if it is though.

Answer (score 0):

[FxCop](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb429476(VS.80).aspx) **had** some advices for that. Check [this article](http://www.codeproject.com/KB/cs/stringperf.aspx)

For instance according to the article in this code:

```
static string BadConcatenate(string[] items)
{
    string strRet = string.Empty;

    foreach(string item in items)
    {
        strRet += item;
    }

    return strRet;
}
```

FxCop reports

```
"Change StringCompareTest.BadConcatenate(String[]):String to use StringBuilder 
  instead of String.Concat or +
```

Edit

It looks like the rule [CA1807](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms182266(VS.80).aspx) has been removed either *because of high noise or no longer applicable analysis*. And it looks like the compiler [is not automatically replacing it](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2177447/why-is-string-concat-not-optimized-to-stringbuilder-append), in the same link they elaborate more on the performance of both methods.

Comment: Apparently the reason I never saw this was that [the particular rule was removed in 2007 or earlier](http://blogs.msdn.com/codeanalysis/archive/2007/08/09/what-rules-do-microsoft-have-turned-on-internally.aspx#5390704).  *"Unfortunately, these rules were based on our old data flow engine and were removed when it was removed from the product. We will be recovering them in a future version of Visual Studio."*