# C# foreach memory cache and string memory optimization

Tags: c#

```
foreach (string sn in MACOrSerial.Split(','))
{
    MACOrSerial = sn.Trim();   
}
```

MACORSerial contains a string of text (EX. AA123241, BB123431, CC1231243) separated by commas.
I grab one substring and place that into the same MACORSerial.

This will not cause me any problems as the the foreach still will be using the **original** MACOrSerial in memory.

While I think this is the most memory efficient approach, is it proper or should I just make another string with a new name such as

```
MacORSerialSubString = sn.Trim()?
```

I am not having any memory issues.  I just want to make sure my code is clean and concise.

Comment: Are you having an actual memory issue with this that you are trying to solve?

Comment: Oded is right. Spend your time solving real problems that are actually causing customer pain. Write your code so that every variable has a clearly understandable purpose, not so that you somehow "optimize" your use of memory.

Comment: I had to read through this code about 5 times before I could grok what was happening.  It's unreadable and likely doesn't address any of the perceived memory issues you're having.

Comment: I just want to make sure my code is intuitive and clean.

Comment: There are no memory problems.

Comment: @HarHaHu - I think you can see by the tenor of the responses that the above approach is neither intuitive or clean.

Comment: Then (1) use one variable to mean *exactly one thing*, and (2) name your variables as *nouns*. *MACOrSerial* -- two adjectives -- should probably be something like "addressList". The inner variable should be something like "trimmedAddress".

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Your assumption is incorrect - the loop goes over the `string[]` resulting from the `Split` - these are all *new* string instances.

You are not saving any memory by reassigning a string to the original variable and you are losing readability by reuse of a variable.

Here is one approach that is more readable and uses some of the built in capabilities:

```
string[] serialNumbers = MACOrSerial.Split(new [] {',', ' ', '\r', '\n' }, 
                                   StringSplitOptions.RemoveEmptyEntries);

foreach (string sn in serialNumbers)
{
    // do stuff
}
```

Comment: +1 thanks, you sure not even .00001 seconds?!? for a new string assignment?

Comment: @HarHaHu - Unless you are working on many millions of records, this is not likely to be of any significance.

Comment: fantastic and comprehensive answer! Thanks.

Comment: @HarHaHu: If you have a performance concern, **measure it** and then you'll know. First, set a performance goal so that you know what acceptable and unacceptable performance is. Then measure your program against the goal. If it is acceptable **do not fix it; it is not broken.** If it is unacceptable then *get a profiler*, *run the profiler*, *find the slowest thing* and *fix that*. The few microseconds it takes to allocate this string is unlikely to be the real problem, so *stop wasting time thinking about how to fix non-problems.* Spend time tracking down and fixing *real* problems.

Answer (score 4):

My $.02- the code as you posted is *extremely* un-intuitive, because it breaks with the expected pattern.

IMHO it is more important to write the code in a way that other developers can understand at a glance than it is to (actually / attempt to) micro-optimize for memory, especially when (as others have pointed out) your micro-optimization does not actually reduce the amount of memory used.

Comment: Sure.  Not to plug my own answer, but you may also want to read what's become a somewhat good reference on how .NET treats strings here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9132338/how-many-string-objects-will-be-created-when-using-a-plus-sign/9132374#9132374, especially the bit at the end about concatenation loops.

Answer (score 2):

I would create a new variable so that your code is more clear. It doesn't have any noticable impact on memory.

Answer (score 1):

For clarity (and later maintaining) of the code, I would prefer use of a separate variable. Plus I would remove the empty strings up front:

```
foreach (string sn in MACOrSerial.Split(',', StringSplitOptions.RemoveEmptyEntries))
{
    string MacORSerialSubString = sn.Trim();
}
```

Answer (score 1):

In reality, your iteration will be using the result of the `MACOrSerial.Split()` call, which is an array that is independent from the `MACOrSeria`l variable.

There will be no difference between using `MACOrSerial` or another string variable in terms of memory usage, each time `sn.Trim()` is called, a new string is generated and it's just the reference to this new string that gets placed in your string variable.