# Why is it Valid to Concatenate Null Strings but not to Call "null.ToString()"?

Tags: c#, .net, string, null

This is valid C# code

```
var bob = "abc" + null + null + null + "123";  // abc123
```

This is not valid C# code

```
var wtf = null.ToString(); // compiler error
```

Why is the first statement valid?

Comment: I find it peculiar that your `null.ToString()` is given the name `wtf`. Why does that surprise you? You can't call an instance method when you have nothing to call it from in the first place.

Comment: @BoltClock: Of course it is possible calling an instance method on a null instance. Just not possible in C#, but very valid on the CLR :)

Comment: The answers with regard to String.Concat are ***almost*** correct.  In fact, the specific example in the question is one of **constant folding**, and the nulls in the first line are eliminated by the compiler- i.e. they are never evaluated at runtime because they don't exist anymore- the compiler has erased them.  I wrote a little monologue on all of the rules for concatenation and  constant folding of Strings over here for more info: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9132338/how-many-string-objects-will-be-created-when-using-a-plus-sign/9132374#9132374.

Comment: you can add nothing to a string but you cant make a string out of nothing.

Comment: Is the second statement not valid? `class null_extension { String ToString( Object this arg ) { return ToString(arg); } }`

Answer (score 171, accepted):

**The reason for first one working:**

From [MSDN](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/how-to/concatenate-multiple-strings):

> In string concatenation operations,the C# compiler treats a null string the same as an empty string, but it does not convert the value of the original null string.

More information on the [+ binary operator](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/language-reference/operators/addition-operator#string-concatenation):

> The binary + operator performs string concatenation when one or both operands are of type string.
>
> If an operand of string concatenation is null, an empty string is substituted. Otherwise, any non-string argument is converted to its string representation by invoking the virtual `ToString` method inherited from type object.
>
> If `ToString` returns `null`, an empty string is substituted.

**The reason of the error in second is:**

[null (C# Reference)](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/language-reference/keywords/null) - The null keyword is a literal that represents a null reference, one that does not refer to any object. null is the default value of reference-type variables.

Comment: Would this work then? var `wtf = ((String)null).ToString();` I'm working in Java recently where casting null's is possible, has been a while since I worked with C#.

Comment: @Jochem: You're still trying to call a method on a null object, so I'm guessing no. Think of it as `null.ToString()` vs `ToString(null)`.

Comment: @Svish yes, now I think of it again, it is a null object, so you're right, it won't work. It wouldn't in Java neither: null pointer exception. Never mind. Tnx for your reply! [edit: tested it in Java: NullPointerException. With the difference that with cast it compiles, without cast it doesn't].

Comment: generally there is no reason to intentionally concat or ToString the null keyword.  If you need an empty string use string.Empty.  if you need to check if a string variable is null you can either use (myString == null) or string.IsNullOrEmpty(myString).   Alternatively to transform a null string variable into string.Empty use myNewString = (myString == null ?? string.Empty)

Comment: @Jochem casting it will make it compile but it will indeed throw a NullReferenceException at runtime

Comment: So *why* does string concatenation work this way? It seems to me this would be likely to mask errors.

Comment: Wouldn't the `+` operator be overloaded to use the `String.Concat()` function? If so, then it would be possible to treat `null` as `String.Empty`, correct?

Answer (score 111):

Because the `+` operator in C# internally translates to `String.Concat`, which is a static method. And this method happens to treat `null` like an empty string. If you look at the source of `String.Concat` in Reflector, you'll see it:

```
// while looping through the parameters
strArray[i] = (str == null) ? Empty : str;
// then concatenate that string array
```

(MSDN mentions it, too: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/k9c94ey1.aspx)

On the other hand, `ToString()` is an instance method, which you cannot call on `null` (what type should be used for `null`?).

Comment: There is no + operator in the String class though.. So is it the compiler translating to String.Concat?

Comment: @superlogical Yes, that is what the compiler does. So actually, the `+` operator on strings in C# is just syntactic sugar for `String.Concat`.

Comment: Adding to that: The compiler automatically picks the overload of Concat that makes most sense. Available overloads are 1, 2 or 3 object parameters, 4 object parameters + `__arglist` and a `params` object array version.

Comment: What string array is being modified there?  Does `Concat` always create a new array of non-null strings even when given an array of non-null strings, or is something else going on?

Comment: @supercat The modified array is a new array, which is then passed to a private helper method. You can look at the code yourself using reflector.

Answer (score 30):

The **first sample** will be translated into:

```
var bob = String.Concat("abc123", null, null, null, "abs123");
```

The `Concat` method checks input and translate null as an empty string

The **second sample** will be translated into:

```
var wtf = ((object)null).ToString();
```

So a `null` reference exception will be generated here

Comment: Actually, a `AccessViolationException` will be thrown :)

Comment: I just did :) `((object)null).ToString()` => `AccessViolation` `((object)1 as string).ToString()` => `NullReference`

Comment: I have got NullReferenceException. DN 4.0

Comment: Interesting. When I put `((object)null).ToString()` inside a `try/catch` I get `NullReferenceException` too.

Comment: DOH, my bad! :*( I was using `((string)null).ToString()`, and that gives the AccessViolation.

Comment: @Ieppie except that doesn't throw AccessViolation either (why would it?) - NullReferenceException here.

Answer (score 12):

The first part of your code is just treated like that in `String.Concat`,

which is what the C# compiler calls when you add strings. "`abc" + null` gets translated to `String.Concat("abc", null)`,

and internally, that method replaces `null` with `String.Empty`. So, that's why your first part of code does not throw any exception. it is just like

```
var bob = "abc" + string.Empty + string.Empty + string.Empty + "123";  //abc123
```

And in 2nd part of your code throws exception because 'null' is not an object, **the null keyword is a literal that represents a null reference**, one that does not refer to any object. null is the default value of reference-type variables.

And '`ToString()`' is a method that can be called by an instance of an object but not any literal.

Comment: `String.Empty` is not equal to `null`. It's just treated the same way in some methods like `String.Concat`. For example, if you have a string variable set to `null`, C# won't replace it with `String.Empty` if you try to call a method on it.

Comment: Almost. `null` is not treated like `String.Empty` by C#, it's just treated like that in `String.Concat`, which is what the C# compiler calls when you add strings. `"abc" + null` gets translated to `String.Concat("abc", null)`, and internally, that method replaces `null` with `String.Empty`. The second part is completely correct.

Answer (score 9):

In the COM framework which preceded .net, it was necessary for any routine which received a string to free it when it was done with it.  Because it was very common for empty strings to be passed into and out of routines, and because attempting to "free" a null pointer was defined as a legitimate do-nothing operation, Microsoft decided to have a null string pointer represent an empty string.

To allow for some compatibility with COM, many routines in .net will interpret a null object as a legal representation as an empty string.  With a couple of slight changes .net and its languages (most notably allowing instance members to indicate "do not invoke as virtual"), Microsoft could have made `null` objects of declared type String behave even more like empty strings.  If Microsoft had done that, it would have also had to make `Nullable<T>` work somewhat differently (so as to allow `Nullable<String>`--something they should IMHO have done anyway) and/or define a `NullableString` type which would be mostly interchangeable with `String`, but which would not regard a `null` as a valid empty string.

As it is, there are some contexts in which a `null` will be regarded as a legitimate empty string and others in which it won't.  Not a terribly helpful situation, but one which programmers should be aware of.  In general, expressions of the form `stringValue.someMember` will fail if `stringValue` is `null`, but most framework methods and operators which accept strings as parameters will regard `null` as an empty string.

Answer (score 5):

`'+'` is an infix operator. Like any operator it is really calling a method. You could imagine a the non-infix version `"wow".Plus(null) == "wow"`

The implementer has decided on something like this...

```
class String
{
  ...
  String Plus(ending)
  {
     if(ending == null) return this;
     ...
  }
}
```

So.. your example becomes

```
var bob = "abc".Plus(null).Plus(null).Plus(null).Plus("123");  // abc123
```

which is the same as

```
var bob = "abc".Plus("123");  // abc123
```

At no point does null become a string. So `null.ToString()` is no different that  `null.VoteMyAnswer()`. ;)

Comment: Really, it's more like `var bob = Plus(Plus(Plus(Plus("abc",null),null),null),"123");`. Operator overloads are static methods at their heart: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/s53ehcz3(v=VS.71).aspx Were they not, `var bob = null + "abc";` or especially `string bob = null + null;` would not be valid.

Comment: You're right, I just felt I would be too confusing if I explain it that way.

Answer (score 3):

I guess because it's a **literal** which doesn't refer to any object. `ToString()` needs an `object`.

Answer (score 2):

Adding `null` to a string is simply ignored. `null` (in your second example) isn't an instance of any object, so it doesn't even have a `ToString()` method. It's just a literal.

Answer (score 2):

Someone said in this discussion thread that **you can't make a string out of nothing.**
(which is a nice phrase as I think). But **yes - you can** :-), as the following example shows:

```
var x = null + (string)null;     
var wtf = x.ToString();
```

works fine and does not throw an exception at all. The only difference is that you need to cast one of the nulls into a string - if you remove the **(string)** cast, then the example still compiles, but throws a run-time exception: "Operator '+' is ambiguous on operands of type '<null>' and '<null>'".

**N.B.** In the code example above, the value of `x` is not null as you might expect, it is actually an empty string after you have casted one of the operands into a string.

Slightly different is `var a = ((string)null).ToString();` - which compiles but will throw a NullReferenceException. In this case the exception is thrown because the `.` operator isn't allowed on null values. Using `?.` would work here (but ToString isn't executed in this case). The compiler will correctly "create" the variable `a` as a string.

---

Another interesting fact is that in C# / .NET **the way `null` is treated is not always the same** if you regard different data types. For example:

```
int? x = 1;  //  string x = "1";
x = x + null + null;
Console.WriteLine((x==null) ? "<null>" : x.ToString());
```

Regard the **1st line** of the code snippet: If `x` is a nullable integer variable (i.e. `int?`) containing value `1`, then you're getting the result `<null>` back. If it is a string (as shown in the comment) with value `"1"`, then you're getting `"1"` back rather than `<null>`.

**N.B.** Also interesting: If you're using `var x = 1;` for the first line, then you're getting a runtime error. Why? Because the assignment will turn the variable `x` into the datatype `int`, which is not nullable. The compiler does not assume `int?` here, and hence fails in the 2nd line where `null` is added.

Answer (score 1):

Because there is no difference between `string.Empty` and `null` when you concat strings.
You can pass null into `string.Format` as well. But you are trying to call a method on `null`, which would always result in a `NullReferenceException` and therefore generates a compiler error.
If for some reason you really want to do it, you could write an extension method, that checks for `null` and then returns `string.Empty`. But an extension like that should only be used when absolutly necessary (in my opinion).

Answer (score 0):

As general: It may or may not valid accepting null as a parameter depending on specification, but it is always invalid to call a method on null.

---

That's and other topic why the + operator's operands can be null in case of strings. This is kinda VB thing (sorry guys) to make programmers life easier, or supposing the programmer can not deal with nulls. I completely disagree this specification. 'unknown' + 'anything' should be still 'unknown'...